# How do I access the rotation and translation vectors after camera calibration in emgu CV?

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, camera-calibration

The goal of a camera calibration is to find the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters:

1. The intrinsic ones are those that describe the camera itself (focal
   length, distortion, etc.) I get values for those, no problem.
2. The extrinsic parameters are basically the position of the camera. When I try to access those I get an `AccessViolationException`.

One way to perform such calibration is to

1. take an image of a calibration target with known corners
2. find those corners in the image
3. from the correspondence between 3D and 2D points, find the matrix that transforms one into the other
4. that matrix consists of the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.

The call to the [calibration function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Tvf.png) looks like this:

```
Mat[] rotationVectors = new Mat[1];
Mat[] translationVectors = new Mat[1];

double error = CvInvoke.CalibrateCamera(realCorners,
                                        detectedCorners,
                                        calibrationImages[0].Image.Size,
                                        cameraMatrix,
                                        distortionCoefficients,
                                        0,
                                        new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1),
                                        out rotationVectors,
                                        out translationVectors);

Console.WriteLine(rotationVectors[0].Size); // AccessViolationException
```

- I only use one image here, but I have the same problem when using more images (30) Different calibration images would yield different results for `translation`-/`rotationVector` anyway, which makes me doubt that using only 1 image is a problem.
- The detection of points works and drawing them into the original image gives reasonabel results.
- Both `cameraMatrix` and `distortionCoefficients` can be accessed and contain values. (I tried to only post the relevant parts of the code)
- I use emgu version 3.0.0.2157

**Why do I get an `AccessViolationException` on the `rotationVectors` and  `translationVectors`?**

I placed a breakpoint and found that the internal `Data` property is `null`. See screenshot of VS debugger:

[image]

That explains why I cannot access it. But **why is it `null`** in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of bug in EmguCV. You are calling

```
public static double CalibrateCamera(
   MCvPoint3D32f[][] objectPoints,
   PointF[][] imagePoints,
   Size imageSize,
   IInputOutputArray cameraMatrix,
   IInputOutputArray distortionCoeffs,
   CvEnum.CalibType calibrationType,
   MCvTermCriteria termCriteria,
   out Mat[] rotationVectors,
   out Mat[] translationVectors)
```

inside this method there is a call to

```
public static double CalibrateCamera(
   IInputArray objectPoints,
   IInputArray imagePoints,
   Size imageSize,
   IInputOutputArray cameraMatrix,
   IInputOutputArray distortionCoeffs,
   IOutputArray rotationVectors,
   IOutputArray translationVectors,
   CvEnum.CalibType flags,
   MCvTermCriteria termCriteria)
```

`IOutputArray rotationVectors` should be copied to `Mat[] rotationVectors`. The same thing in case of translationVectors. The problem is in [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/3.0.0/tree/Emgu.CV/PInvoke/CvInvokeCalib3d.cs#l346) loop.

There is

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
{
   rotationVectors[i] = new Mat();
   using (Mat matR = rotationVectors[i]) // <- bug
      matR.CopyTo(rotationVectors[i]);
   translationVectors[i] = new Mat();
   using (Mat matT = translationVectors[i]) // <- bug
      matT.CopyTo(translationVectors[i]);                
}
```

and there should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
{
   rotationVectors[i] = new Mat();
   using (Mat matR = rVecs[i]) 
      matR.CopyTo(rotationVectors[i]);
   translationVectors[i] = new Mat();
   using (Mat matT = tVecs[i]) 
      matT.CopyTo(translationVectors[i]);                
}
```

Finally to get rotation and translation values you can copy data using `DataPointer`

```
var rotation = new Matrix<float>(rotationVectors[0].Rows, rotationVectors[0].Cols, rotationVectors[0].DataPointer);
```

Comment: I wrote my own function that changes those lines. I can indeed access the values. They are very different from what I get from SolvePnP, but at least I can access them. Thanks!

Comment: @Bartosz Rachwal and null , sorry for ask but my cvInoke.SolvePnP do no want to accept Mat[] rotationVector, is working only with Emgu.CV.Matrix<float> rotationVector.  What can I do to read the rotation? I hope you can help me